# How can you tell from a diagram if resistors are in parallel?

Tags: circuit-design

For example:

[image]

How can I tell if the 820R and 390R resistors are in parallel or series? Is there something specific I should look for in the diagram that would tell me this?

Ans:

[image]

Comment: You don't.  You tell the person that gave you the cartoon that you refuse to look at it, and to come back with a proper schematic if he wants to be taken seriously.

Comment: @OlinLathrop obviously, OP is having some kind of starter kit and tries to *learn* seeing schematics from wiring illustrations.

Comment: @Sarah, however, you're asking questions about inductance, and other physical effects. Go get a small introduction to schematics. Olin is right, discussing this is really feeble – if you knew how to draw a schematic, the answer to your question would be **obvious** in the literal sense.

Comment: The layout diagram and the circuit diagram are different circuits.  Either the book is wrong, or you've gotten the diagrams mixed up.

Comment: The answer you show is wrong.  The schematic and the wiring diagram show two different circuits.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Series and parallel connection]

from Figure as you can see, for SERIES connection there is only one common point (and no other branches should be there)  while for PARALLEL connection they have two common points(they may have branches)

in your figure, 390R & 820R have only one common point hence they are in series.

Answer (score 1):

The resistors are connected in series. The grid configuration used resembles a breadboard. Refer to [this](http://www.tweaking4all.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/basic_breadboard_layout.png) image if you are not familiar with a breadboard configuration.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I thought, but the answer shows they are in parallel? Maybe it is wrong

Comment: To me it also seems like the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Two dipoles are in parallel if there is a loop in the diagram including both dipoles and no other parts.

Two dipoles are in series if any loop in the diagram including one dipole also includes the other.

In your diagram, there is only one loop including both resistors, along with other components. Thus, your resistors are in series.

Comment: FYI, in English, the word "dipole" refers to a kind of antenna, not a  category of passive components you might find on a PCB or IC. Unfortunately we don't have any good single word for a two-terminal device and we have to use the phrase "two-terminal device" or something similar.

Comment: @ThePhoton In graph theory (which is also used to solve problems in electrical circuits) the dipole is a graph with only two vertices conected with *n* parallel edges. Especially if *n* is equal to 1 we obviously have "two-terminal element".

Comment: @lustful-rat, that just adds more confusion when somebody uses the word *dipole* to refer to a component (that would only make up one of the edges in the graph representation of the circuit).

Answer (score 0):

Either it's answer wrong or the author doesn't know the difference between series and paralel.
It's the thing, that 2 elements are in series, if they have only 1 common point, whie they're paralel, if they share input and output.
I hope I was clear with that.